# URL No Longer Exists when putting a VF page on page layout

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page which I wrote, and put it within the Opportunity page layout.
This is working for a long time. Starting yesterday, I'm getting this error and the Opportunity page does not load.

> URL No Longer Exists

When I remove the VF page everything is fine.
This is the URL I see on the page with the URL error, where 066b0000001ZhB5 is my custom vf page

> https://eu2.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=066b0000001ZhB5&ic=1&nonce=6056f865493bcca791f5a199e27562b5c8dc7b0dfbfd9be6e65f417372a9ff3c&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Feu2.salesforce.com&isdtp=vw

Why is this suddenly happening? How do fix this?

Comment: Have you changed the security settings for the page - e.g. removed access for any profiles?

Comment: No, I haven't touched anything. The only recent change is that we installed the Zendesk app but it should not affect anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like this is the new clickjacking protection in Winter 13. I think I read somewhere recently that this was defaulting on in all Orgs, but I can't recall where.

See [VisualForce components in Page Layouts causing "URL No Longer Exists" error](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=VisualForce-components-in-Page-Layouts-causing-URL-No-Longer-Exists-error&language=en_US)

> **Knowledge Article Number: 000170866**
>
> **Description**
>   Including visualforce pages in page layouts causes the page to not load and receives error: URL No Longer Exist. The URL that the error refers to is the servlet/servlet.integration trying to load the visualforce page.
>
> **Resolution**
>   Staring with Winter 13 release salesforce added a new feature in Setup -> Security Controls -> Session Setting -> 
>   Enable clickjack protection for non-setup customer Visualforce pages.
>
> Enabling this option will cause this error. To correct the situation simply disable this option.

Comment: It seems it is "Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers", what has to be disabled meanwhile.

Comment: @eceeb Sorry, I don't follow what the question is. You can toggle the feature at `Setup -> Security Controls -> Session Setting -> Enable clickjack protection for non-setup customer Visualforce pages` according to the docs above.

Comment: I had no question at all. Sorry for beeing unclear. My comment was about the current solution to the problem.